# Type ObservableDictionary cannot be found in visual studio community 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

In the Visual Studio Community MainPage.xaml.cs file containing the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        ///private NavigationHelper navigationHelper; ///not needed in Visual Studio 2017
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }

        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }

        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

... the line

```
private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
```

produces the following error message:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ObservableDictionary' could not 
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What library am I supposed to include to make this error message go away?

Comment: I'm not very sure if ObservableDictionary is part of the framework. I've just found ObservableCollection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: No such class in .NET.  There are several other options online - is this code you wrote yourself or got from somewhere else?

Comment: I got it from the book Head First C#

Comment: the thing is: if I comment it out and then run the program, the build is created without error message but the app consists of a white screen only

Comment: Why I only get a white screen I don't know but I thought maybe it's because this dictionary or collection is missing

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is too old, but Head First C# used a Common folder, that has this ReadMe:

> The Common directory contains classes and XAML styles that simplify application development.
>
> These are not merely convenient, but are required by most Visual
>   Studio project and item templates. If you need a variation on one of
>   the styles in StandardStyles it is recommended that you make a copy in
>   your own resource dictionary.  When right-clicking on a styled control
>   in the design surface the context menu includes an option to Edit a
>   Copy to simplify this process.
>
> Classes in the Common directory form part of your project and may be
>   further enhanced to meet your needs.  Care should be taken when
>   altering existing methods and properties as incompatible changes will
>   require corresponding changes to code included in a variety of Visual
>   Studio templates.  For example, additional pages added to your project
>   are written assuming that the original methods and properties in
>   Common classes are still present and that the names of the types have
>   not changed.

In the VS2013 solution common folder (there is a VS2012 too, with totally different classes) these are the cs files:
[image]

To use these classes you have to add:

```
using Save_the_Humans.Common;
```

HFC# had not once in the book cited or referred to these classes; I'm assuming that they were boilerplate code at that time; they wrap some Interfaces and Dictionaries:

```
public class ObservableDictionary : IObservableMap<string, object>
{
    private class ObservableDictionaryChangedEventArgs : IMapChangedEventArgs<string>
    {
        public ObservableDictionaryChangedEventArgs(CollectionChange change, string key)
        {
            this.CollectionChange = change;
            this.Key = key;
        }

        public CollectionChange CollectionChange { get; private set; }
        public string Key { get; private set; }
```

...

You can get the C# code - not only the common folder - from [them](https://github.com/head-first-csharp/third-edition) with the VS2012 version too or from my [repository](https://github.com/msdiniz/Save-the-Humans.git) with only VS2013; from their repository you cannot open or import into VS2017 - at least I couldn't; mine is already fresh made with VS2017.

Hope it helps someone.